# Loading multiple workspaces into R at once

Tags: r

Consider having many *.Rda files in your directory. They all contain exactly one object (in this case, a model obtained from mboost:::gamboost) with the added twist, that the objects have the same name ("mod_gam").

Is it possible to load all of them into workspace at once (and even renaming them)?

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="*.Rda")
models <- lapply(temp, load)
```

does yield a list with empty characters:

```
str(models)
List of 26
 $ : chr "mod_gam"
 $ : chr "mod_gam"
 $ : chr "mod_gam"
```

... and so on.

Comment: Load. Rename. Lather. Rinse. Repeat.

Comment: This what i am doing now :>

Comment: The default for 'load' is to overwrite named items so either write a function that prevents that or use rds storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to add an iterative suffix to your objects as they are loaded in. Since you already know that every object loaded in will be called "mod_gam", it makes things a bit easier.

```
i <- 1
for(each in temp){
    load(each)
    eval(parse(text=paste(paste0("mod_gam_",i),"<- mod_gam")))
    i <- i+1
}
```

This will give you the 26 different objects. Note that this isn't optimal -- I wanted to lapply instead of loop, but I was having trouble figuring out how to iterate the suffix each time I read in a new file.